# (Unity3D) Serializedobject target has been destroyed

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

ERROR MESSAGE :

> "Serializedobject target has been destroyed. 
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32,IntPtr)"

I get this error msg 8 times after pressing the play button.

I upgrade from Unity 2017 to Unity 2018 beta (2018.1.0b7), and start getting this error 8 times every time I press the play button, the project runs normally but the sky box disappears from Skybox material in >lighting>scene bar

Hope there is an easy way to fix it.

Comment: File for bug report since Unity 2018 is new and still in beta phase. Issues like these are expected.

Comment: hope it get fixed in the next update than, thx u!

Comment: Bug reports for Unity beta are usually on high priority list. It should be fixed if you file for a bug report or maybe next two releases if your bug report is made late.

Comment: Just in case you didn't try it. Could attempt to restart your computer to see if that fixes it.